# How to rerender the parent component by using the button in child component using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

Parent Component `Assessment.js`

```
import Header from './Header'
import { Button, Dialog } from '@material-ui/core';
import Dialog1 from './Dialog1'
import {Modal, Button as ButtonBootstrap} from 'react-bootstrap';


const Assessment = () => {
    const [show1, setShow1] = useState(false);

    const handleClose1 = () => setShow1(false);
    const handleShow1 = () => setShow1(true);

    return (
        <div> 
           
            <Dialog1 show1={show1} handleClose1={handleClose1} setShow1={setShow1}/>


            <Header/>
            <div className="d-flex flex-row">
                <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-start m-3 mx-5">
                    <div className='m-2 mx-5 visible' style={{borderRadius: "15px", padding: "10px", 
                         paddingRight:"25px", backgroundColor:"#00CCFF"}}>
                        <h5 className='font-weight-bold'>Are you having any of these following:-</h5>
                        <div className='d-flex flex-row'>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Extremely difficult to breath</li>
                                <li>Severe Chest pain.</li>
                                <li>Having a tough time awakening</li>
                                <li>Losing consciousness</li>
                            </ul>
                            <Button onClick={handleShow1}
                             className="mx-5 my-4 align-content-around" 
                             variant="contained" 
                            style={{maxWidth: "30px", maxHeight: "30px"}}>
                                Yes
                            </Button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
)
}
export default Assessment
```

Child Component `Dialog1.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import {Modal, Button as ButtonBootstrap} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Stage1 from '../images/nurse level 0.png';
import Assessment from './Assessment';

const Dialog1 = ({show1, handleClose1, reload}) => {

     function rerender() {
        reload();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Modal show={show1} onHide={handleClose1}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <span className=" d-flex justify-content-center" style={{marginLeft: "150px"}}>
                    <img src={Stage1} class=" img-fluid d-block rounded " alt="nurse_image_1" style={{height: "165px"}}/>
                    </span>
                    
                </Modal.Header>

                <Modal.Body className="conatainer-fluid m-auto">
                    <h4 className="font-weight-bold mx-3">
                        These symptoms are the sign of coronavirus.
                        Please call 9-1-1 or call the Emergency 
                        Department for help!
                    </h4>
                </Modal.Body>

                <Modal.Footer className="d-flex justify-content-center mx-auto">
                    <ButtonBootstrap onClick={} variant="primary" size="lg" active> //want to rerender the parent component
                        Retake Self-Assessment
                    </ButtonBootstrap>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Dialog1
```

I have tried forceupdate() method but it didn't worked if someone can tell me better idea for this.
also i think history.goback will not be appropriate for this. I have tried to pass the method inside parent component to get called when the button inside child component is clicked.

Comment: Have you tried passing state from child to parent and then doing a useEffect in the parent component to drive a re-render?